# How to understand the throw method of JavaScript Generator?

Tags: javascript

This is my snippet of code.

```js
var g = function*() {
  try {
    yield;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("inner catch", e);
  }
};

var i = g();
i.next();

try {
  i.throw("a");
  i.throw("b");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("outer catch", e);
}
```

I expect this result :

```
inner catch a
inner catch a
```

So why the inner catch of `generator` can not catch twice?

Comment: After the `yield` has thrown, your generator has finished execution, there is no second `yield` encountered where it would wait again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your generator moved to the `catch` after the first `throw()`, so there's no `try` available to catch the second one, so the exception propagates from its call position.

```js
var g = function*() {
  try {
   yield;
  } catch (e) {
   console.log("inner catch", e); 
   try {
     yield;
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("inner catch 2", e);
   }
  }
};

var i = g();
i.next();

try {
  i.throw("a");
  i.throw("b");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("outer catch", e);
}
```

To not have to nest `try/catch` statements, you'd need a loop.

```js
var g = function*() {
  while (true) {
   try {
    yield;
   } catch (e) {
    console.log("inner catch", e); 
    if (e === "b") {
      console.log("breaking loop");
      break;
    }
   }
  }
};

var i = g();
i.next();

try {
  i.throw("a");
  i.throw("b");
  i.throw("c");
} catch (e) {
  console.log("outer catch", e);
}
```